# Set iOS style accessoryType in Android table row in NativeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I have some code in NativeScript that sets the iOS accessoryType in a list view on tap of the row but I don't know how to do this the Android section.

Code I have working is:

```
if (args.ios) {
    args.ios.accessoryType = 3;
} else if (args.android) {
    // Set the Android indicator here.
}
```

I'm not an Android developer so I have no idea where to start.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't have such feature out of the box. If you prefer a cross platform solution, then you should design your template with a similar icon placed at the corner.